# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined in respone of axios get data in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Am trying to place autosuggest with api result.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Autosuggest from "react-autosuggest";
import axios from "axios";

// When suggestion is clicked, Autosuggest needs to populate the input
// based on the clicked suggestion. Teach Autosuggest how to calculate the
// input value for every given suggestion.
const getSuggestionValue = suggestion => suggestion.city;

// Use your imagination to render suggestions.
const renderSuggestion = suggestion => <div>{suggestion.city}</div>;

class Autocomplete extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      suggestions: []
    };
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
  };

  getData(value) {
    var itemslist = {};
    axios
      .get(
        "https://abcdgf/api/cities?page=1&perPage=1000&search=" +
          value
      )
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.status);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          itemslist = response.data.data;
          console.log(itemslist);
          this.setState({
            suggestions: itemslist.filter(
              lang => lang.city.toLowerCase().slice(0, value.length) === value
            )
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  // Autosuggest will call this function every time you need to update suggestions.
  // You already implemented this logic above, so just use it.
  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    if (value.length > 2) {
      this.getData(value.trim().toLowerCase());
    }
  };

  // Autosuggest will call this function every time you need to clear suggestions.
  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: []
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { value, suggestions } = this.state;

    // Autosuggest will pass through all these props to the input.
    const inputProps = {
      placeholder: "Type a programming language",
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange
    };

    // Finally, render it!
    return (
      <Autosuggest
        suggestions={suggestions}
        onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
        onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
        getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
        renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
        inputProps={inputProps}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default Autocomplete;
```

At line no 49 in getData function, its giving an error saying that  Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined. Actually getData is declared in constructor. If i remove this axios then it is working properly. please let me know what is the error in this. thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to have a better understanding about JS `this` scope and `lexical this` with ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In then use either arrow function or bind this

```
then((response) => {
    console.log(response.status);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      itemslist = response.data.data;
      console.log(itemslist);
      this.setState({
        suggestions: itemslist.filter(
          lang => lang.city.toLowerCase().slice(0, value.length) === value
        )
      });
    }
  })
```

Because function in then is a callback which will be get called later and in case of normal function ( non arrow function ) this points to object which calls the functions so this inside callback won't point to your AutoComplete class object that's why you're getting error

Comment: Thanks for the reply. issue got resolved.